# How to get maven-project install directory from pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

Is there a way to get a maven project install directory from property in the **pom.xml**? Something like lets say `${project.install.directory}`, I know there is `${project.build.directory}` which points to target folder, but I need this ***C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\com\demo\1.0-SNAPSHOT***.

Comment: Why do you need this information?

Comment: I cannot clean install and then redeploy from ${project.build.directory} because the war is used from the application server (the problem is with clean command). But if I was using the install directory I would not have this issue because the clean command does not delete the war from there.

Comment: `mvn clean install`

Comment: Which application server?

Comment: I use weblogic 12.1.3

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is one property, that would do exactly, what you want.
However you can try to glue together these properties to make yourself a "project.install.directory" property:

**${settings.localRepository}** will point to your local repository - "C:\Users\user.m2\repository"

**${project.groupId}**

**${project.artifactId}**

**${project.version}**

**${project.build.finalName}**

Comment: Thank you, I have tried: `${settings.localRepository}/${project.groupId}/${project.artifactId}/${project.version}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}` (notice that I added `${project.packaging}`)
the problem is that `${project.groupId}` has a dot delimiter like this `com.demo` but I need somehow to replace the dot with a slash `com/demo`